# Are homemade toothpastes as effective as industrial toothpastes?

Tags: dentistry, risks, hygiene, minerals, toothpaste

There are a lot of recipes in the internet of homemade toothpastes (see [this link](http://wellnessmama.com/2500/remineralizing-toothpaste/) or [this link](http://realfoodoutlaws.com/diy-clay-toothpaste/) as examples).

Most of the recipes remark the benefits of using these toothpastes to promote remineralization. I've just started trying on of these clay-based toothpastes and I was wondering two things.

First, are they as effective in terms of dental hygiene a industrial toothpastes?

Second, are there any health hazards regarding this toothpastes?

P.S. I don't know if I should post this as one or two different questions.